# SetIinterval/Polling every 5 seconds resets the values of my state variables/args instead of keeping the most recently set ones?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

So in my primary React component where I'm making a GET request, I have

```
const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState('')

const [numericalArg, setNumericalArg] = useState('')
/* or I have */:
const numericalArg = useRef('')

const handleTopRequest = (arg1) => {
  url = "base_url" + `?${numericalArg}`
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      setResponse(response)
    }
}

  useEffect(() => {
    handleTopRequest(sortByParam);
    const intervalId = setInterval(handleTopRequest, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  const handleNumArgChange = (event) => {
    setNumericalArg(event.target.value);
    // numProcesses.current = event.target.value;
  };

return
  <div>
          <label>
            Number of Processes:
            <input
              type="number"
              value={numericalArg}
              onChange={handleNumArgChange}/>
          </label>
...
   <div>{JSON.stringify(responseData)}</div>
  </div>
```

I have an input field where I can set numericalArg to whatever integer I'd like (like 59). However, when the interval fires, numericalArg gets reset to essentially nothing, instead of the ideal value of 59.

How do I fix this? I tried using useRef(), and it kinda works (?), but it's not *consistent at all* and even breaks the input field many times (for example, I can't even type in any numbers in the input field for numericalArg for some reason).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is a stale closure over the `numericalArg` state value in the `handleTopRequest` handler. The `useEffect` hook runs once after the component mounts, closes over the initial `numericalArg` value, i.e `""`, and instantiates the interval. The interval calls this same instance of the `handleTopRequest` callback each time.

## Solution

I think you are on the right track trying to use a React ref. Use a React ref and a `useEffect` hook to cache the current state value, and access the ref's current value in the `handleTopRequest` callback function.

Example:

```js
const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState('');
const [numericalArg, setNumericalArg] = useState('');

// Ref to hold current state value
const numericalArgRef = useRef(numericalArg);

// Effect to cache current state value when it updates
useEffect(() => {
  numericalArgRef.current = numericalArg;
}, [numericalArg]);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleTopRequest = () => {
    // Access current numericalArgRef value
    url = "base_url" + `?${numericalArgRef.current}`;

    axios.get(url).then(setResponse);
  };

  handleTopRequest();

  const intervalId = setInterval(handleTopRequest, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, []);

const handleNumArgChange = (event) => {
  setNumericalArg(event.target.value);
};

return (
  <div>
    <label>
      Number of Processes:
      <input
        type="number"
        value={numericalArg}
        onChange={handleNumArgChange}
      />
    </label>
    ...
    <div>{JSON.stringify(responseData)}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Would this work with say a button (as opposed to an input field)?

Comment: @Yajax I am inclined to say yes, since this is an issue of Javascript Closures, but can you explain a bit more your question?

Comment: Oh yeah of course! Sorry. As opposed to an input field, let's say I have a button that, when clicked, generates the number 59 (initially, the default value is nothing/not loaded yet). And it should remain that way during 5 sec polls/re-renders. Would your above implementation, adapted for that use case button, still work or are there other changes I need to be aware of?

Comment: @Yajax Ah, then yes, it should work. The solution here is fixing the stale closure and allows callbacks to access whatever the current state is. It doesn't really matter what or how that state is updated. It could be user input, a button, another `useEffect` fetching data, another interval/timer, etc. Hopefully this all makes sense.